# Delete all product attributes magento

Tags: magento

What is the fastest way to delete all attribute options from magento.  I'm refering to the stored multi-select options / drop down items that are created when importing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to run direct sql command:

```
DELETE options FROM eav_attribute AS attribute INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option AS options ON attribute.attribute_id = options.attribute_id WHERE attribute.entity_type_id = 4
```

Where "4" is the entity_type_id for catalog_product (double check this value in your eav_entity_type table for entity_code 'catalog_product')

Comment: Does this method delete the association between the products and that attribute?